# rails show calculated field before create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, wizard, actioncontroller

I have a budget model where I have a method called `calculate_budget`

```
class Budget < ActiveRecord::Base

# Assoziations
  belongs_to :member
  belongs_to :donation

# Callbacks
  after_create :calculate_budget, :transfer_old_remaining_promise_to_current_budget

# Public: It is called immediatly after creating (callback) a budget model and it's
#         calculating the budget "promise" (column) based on "donation formula"
#         and income of the member.
#
# Returns:
#         true or false
  def calculate_budget
    ...
    ...
  end
```

I want to show to the budget creator (user) the value that is calculated in the controller/view before saving it. Potentially the user should able to edit it before saving it to `promise` column.

I'm currently searching for a idea how to implement the flow and present the calculated value.

Comment: You will need to do this on a client side or to make an AJAX request.

Comment: as @BroiSatse said create a new action in controller let say `projected_budget`  calculate your budget in there and show it to user. do all this in a ajax call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several possibilities depending on your desired user experience and limitations. Here are 3 of them.

1. Add a preview button that refreshes the page.

   That button would call an action that adds all the data to the `Budget` and renders back the same view without saving your `Budget`. The user would then be able to change the `promise` value and then submit the form.

   ```
   class BudgetsController < ApplicationController
     def new
       @budget = Budget.new
     end

     def create
       @budget = Budget.new(create_params)
       ... # save, redirect and whatever else
     end

     def preview
       @budget = Budget.new(create_params)
       # Check validity of the data if calculate_budget does not
       @budget.calculate_budget # Assuming this method does not save the budget
       render :new
     end

     ...
   end
   ```

   With this controller, just add the `promise` field to your view and it will be filled after submitting data to the `preview` action.
2. Query the `promise` using AJAX

   Implement an action that renders the `promise` value as plain text or json and use javascript to display that value in the form. This approach would avoid the page refresh.
3. Calculate it with javascript

   Implement the logic of your `promise` calculation in javascript and display it as the user is filling the form. This usually looks and feels the best to the user, but has several drawbacks. Namely the fact that you need to duplicate your logic and in some cases might not even be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Depends how you want to do it. I'll give you a server-side solution; if no one jumps in first I'll do `ajax` as well. Basically we can hijack the familiar new -> errors on method -> render new again flow:

- Add a 'virtual' boolean attribute for your model `attr_accessor :budget_reviewed`
- Have your budget method do `validate :budget_review_needed`
- That method should do `errors :add :budget, 'needs to be reviewed' unless budget_reviewed` (could be wrong on syntax)
- In order to add the actual `budget` attribute, you need to look for a confirmation that you have reviewed the budget. That's where `budget_reviewed` comes in
- Have user enter their budget data (this would happen in your controller's `new` method for instance)
- They won't have a way to enter `budget_reviewed` in the params - we'll add that check for the view
- First go around that `@budget = Budget.new(budget_params); @budget.save` gets called it will fail with an error on `:budget` with text `needs to be reviewed`

something like this:

```
def create
  @budget = Budget.new budget_params
  if @budget.save
    redirect_to budgets_path
  else
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

- Look for that error on your view, and if you find it both show the calculated budget and add a checkbox in your form that says `I have reviewed the budget`
- If the user clicks the checkbox, the value should travel through `params` into your attributes for the `@budget`, and should save knowing that budget has been confirmed.
- Profit (pun intended)

Arguably `ajax` is cleaner, but this is also possible.